# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SET' and also giving me some warnings

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone please help me out with the warnings in the below query

```
CREATE FUNCTION MyRound(@Operand Float,@Places INT) 
RETURNS Float
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @x Float;
    DECLARE @i INT;
    DECLARE @ix Float;

      SET @x = @Operand*Power(10,@Places);
      SET @i=@x;

      IF ((@i-@x) >= 0.5) 
      Begin                   
        SET @ix = 1;   
        End               
      ELSE
      Begin
        SET @ix = 0;  
        End               
      END ;     

      SET @x=@i+@ix;
      SET @x=@x/Power(10,@Places);

    RETURN @x;
END
```

I am getting 3 different warnings

1. Create Function must be the only statement in the batch
2. Must Declare Scalar Variable
3. Incorrect syntax near End of File. Expecting CONVERSATION.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See lines

```
  Begin
        SET @ix = 0;  
        End               
      END ;
```

remove one not expected End

Comment: Ooops, i didnt notice that...Thanks a lot @dimaSUN